will it raise higher cost when setComputeUnitLimit to higer and higher CU than actually used?
From my first impression, the setComputeUnitLimit() just set the cap of execute unit, so, said Tx actually need 300_000 CU, then I can call setComputeUnitLimit() with any value that higher than 300_000, there is no different bwteeen 500_000, 700_000, 900_000 ...
But some of my colleage not sure of this and worry that all provided CU by setComputeUnitLimit() will be consumed.
Which is right? And how to create a test to verify the conclusion?

Short answer is no: currently the cost-per-CU is not implemented on mainnet as of April 2024. Eventually, it will be!
Also, it currently does not really matter how much you pay in priority fees. Txes with a priority fee will be more likely to be processed and increasing the fee does not typically make a difference. This is because RPCs typically group txes into "fee or not" and not sorted by fee/unit.
There is a big catch though: the more CU you request, the less likely your tx is to be processed. The technical reason for this is basically that each block has some amount of CU available (let's say 2 million) and the RPC will essentially put txes in the queue to execute at random. If the queue is close to full (let's say 1.5 million out of 2 million is used up, so 500k is available) and your 900k CU tx comes in, it'll get dropped, while the 400k tx would be added to the queue.

The catch you point out is interest and make sense.
Though, you said that cost-per-CU is not implemented on mainnet, it is unbelievable. Can you share more material to support this point?

Here's a link with an example program: https://www.rareskills.io/post/solana-compute-unit-price. My answer also somewhat ignores the new SetComputePrice (aka the priority fee) ix from the Compute Budget Program, which is Solana's current way to implement "cost-per-CU", but is technically optional and doesn't appreciably increase your tx's odds to get picked up (usually). See https://www.helius.dev/blog/priority-fees-understanding-solanas-transaction-fee-mechanics for details.

Your impression of setComputeUnitLimit() is indeed correct. This function is used to set the maximum number of compute units (CUs) that the transaction is allowed to consume. If the actual compute units required for executing the transaction are less than the limit set, only the required amount will be consumed, not the full amount specified by the limit.
This is useful for ensuring your transaction does not exceed a certain budget and ensures your transactions are processed within the resource limits you specify
For instance, if you set the compute unit limit to 500,000 but the transaction only needs 300,000 compute units, it will only consume 300,000 CUs.
If the transaction tries to exceed this cap during execution, it will fail.
How to Test and Verify:
To verify how setComputeUnitLimit() behaves, you can create a test where you measure the actual compute units consumed by a transaction. Here’s a basic outline for such a test using Solana's development tools:
Execute the transaction with a compute unit limit just above the expected consumption (e.g., if expected is 300,000, set it at 310,000).
Execute the same transaction with a higher limit (e.g., 500,000 and 700,000).
Measure and Compare:
Use simulateTransaction RPC calls to simulate the transactions and retrieve the number of compute units actually used.
Compare the compute units consumed in each transaction to verify if the set limit affects the actual usage.
https://solana.com/docs/core/fees
https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-request-optimal-compute

@Whiteseal not really sure where you get that setComputeUnitLimit has not been released but https://solana.com/docs/intro/transaction-fees and https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-request-optimal-compute,
Not sure who downvoted my answer or why my answer has been downvoted at all.

Thanks for great detail explaination. I'm absolute agree with you. Maybe it is better to:  check the accout balance change of Txs of different CU.

@ChristianLiz-Fonts I think most people are downvoting your answer because it looks a bit too heavily created by chatgpt. Figuring out the meat of the answer from the llm answer is really hard.

@JacobCreech Don't think that should be a problem, the OP asked various questions so I made sure to include a answer for all of them as well as including how consensus and the blockchain itself guards against overcharging as well.

@JacobCreech OP upvoted and found it useful so I believe it would have been around the point of someone believing that at the time of writing CU limits could not be placed.

@ChristianLiz-Fonts in general chatgpt generated answered are not allowed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned I've had quite a large number of flags on your posts from other users because of this

@JacobCreech Ahh lol if I just went with what ChatGPT says I wouldn't get anywhere, to write a fully functional code your not just going to go to ChatGPT, if I utilize ChatGPT as a tool in my day to day activities then I am still going to find myself in the docs more then with ChatGPT at the time correcting it. I am not agreeing nor denying anything but I do like to utilize ChatGPT at times also to help speed up processes etc say here I have side projects being worked on not looking to be paid on here helping etc etc right just apart from likes that is the most I can ask for.

@JacobCreech
"Overall, because the average rate of getting correct answers from ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies is too low, the posting of answers created by ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies is substantially harmful to the site and to users who are asking questions and looking for correct answers."
If you look at my answers I would say I have about a 90% passing rate+ as these again are answers based on my thoughts and knowledge so being harmful here I am not.
Some users think ChatGPT you just ask it what to do and you will have a full program or something ;)

Someone can have a avg rating of correct answers of 10% or less as most and even ChatGPT won't help them get a better rating ^.^ it's not the tool it's the person lol. @JacobCreech

Also I have worked on CumputeUnit and Compute Budget Program prior to answering, I have touched on this before answering so found it worth answering here.  @JacobCreech

But also ty for the link, have read into it. Will make sure to structure my answers more accordingly @JacobCreech

Could you reformat this answer? This answer keeps getting flagged for deletion. It'll get auto-deleted if it keeps getting flagged.

@JacobCreech yeaup, let me reach a stopping point on what I am working on and will do so.
